# Different margins for title page

Tags: margins, titles, geometry

My document class is `article` with `a4paper`. The margins that I want for the body are:

```
top: 1 inch
bottom: 1 inch
right: 0.5 inch
left: 1.5 inch
```

The title page should have a 1 inch margin on all four sides, but the body of my paper should have margins as specified above.

I tried using the `geometry` package to specify these margins. But it didn't come out as I wanted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I re-arranged your question a bit to separate info and question and to make it clearer what you're looking for, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Using the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) it is possible to switch your layout mid-document using the `\newgeometry{<settings>}` macro. We first set up the initial layout of the title page (`1in` on all four sides) when the package is loaded

```
\usepackage[showframe,paper=a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

and then change this after the title page using

```
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=1.5in}
```

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paper=a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\author{Somebody Important}
\title{Something just as important}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{titlepage}

\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=1.5in}

\section{First section} \lipsum[1-4]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[5-8]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[9-12]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[13-16]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text, while the `showframe` option to `geometry` merely frames the page to highlight the layout of the text block and other areas.

Comment: Just a slight improvement to @Werner 's answer. Changing the global margins to suit the title page can mess up the headers and footers for the rest of the document. A solution is to set the desired global margin and then add `\newgeometry{<title page settings>}` and `\newgeometry{<global settings>}` before and after `\begin{titlepage}` respectively.

Comment: @Werner, could margin be changed for a specific line only? For example, I want to adjust the margin of the university logo in my title page and move it a bit more left.

Answer (score 50):

Using `\restoregeometry` yields the same results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paper=a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=0.5in,left=1.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}

% Declare new goemetry for the title page only.
\newgeometry{margin=1in}
%---------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\author{Somebody Important}
\title{Something just as important}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{titlepage}

% Ends the declared geometry for the titlepage
\restoregeometry
%--------------------------

\section{First section} \lipsum[1-4]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[5-8]
\section{Third section} \lipsum[9-12]
\section{Last section} \lipsum[13-16]
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: could margin be changed for a specific line only? For example, I want to adjust the margin of the university logo on my title page and want to decrease its left margin.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend to set up the title page as a separate small tex file and including the resulting pdf in the main document using package `pdfpages`.

The content of the titlepage is static anyway, needs extra attention and is the one (hopefully) place in the document where semantinc markup is not needed. There is no real need to keep it with the other stuff. It also ensures correct counting of pages, meaning you don't get in trouble with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{titlepage}
%Acknowledgements, Dedication, Wombats, Ducks etc.
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```