# Change margins for title page

Tags: margins, titles, geometry

I am trying to change the margins for the title page - especially the top margin of the title page. How do I go about decreasing this? So, in my report, on the first page (title), the heading has a "large" top margin, and I would like to reduce this.

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
```

When I do the above, the margins seem to change for a number of pages, and I do not want this - I would like default behaviour everywhere, expcept the title page, where I would like a "lesser" top margin.

When I just do for example:

```
\usepackage[top=3cm]{geometry}
```

it seems to screw up my other margins (left, right) too, which I do not want.
Would be grateful for any suggestions as to how this can be accomplished.

Comment: `geometry.sty` (version 5.6) has the commands `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`.  Have you tried them?

Comment: What class are you even using? An MWE might be helpful. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.