# Different margins for document title only

Tags: margins, titles

I am trying to follow the formatting requirements for a specific conference which state that the document title must have 1.5 inch left and right margins while the rest of the paper must have 1 inch margins.

I have tried the solution shown here: [Different margins for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page)

However, I need the text following the title to be on the same page as the title. How can I get different margins for the document title and the document text while both appear on the same page?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1.5in,left=1.5in}
\title{A long title that wraps onto a second line to show where the margin is}
\author{\normalsize Author A. Name\\\normalsize email@example.com\\\normalsize Awesome Department\\\normalsize Big Deal University}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\restoregeometry

\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use an environment like quote which just changes the margin locally, but if it is just for the title in a specific document, if teh title is centred you don't need to do anything other than force line breaks with `\\ ` if a line is too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\newgeometry`, `\restoregeometry` from the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1.5in}
\lipsum[1-5]% your title information here
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-5]% your document here

\end{document}
```

[image]

The answer above assumed that the titling infomation should appear on a page of its own; after the edit to the original question it is clear that this is not the case; the titling information is produced using \maketitle and the document text should begin immediately afterwards.

In this case, the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package can be used; a patching of `\@maketitle` does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\title{A long title that wraps onto a second line to show where the margin is; some more text}
\author{\normalsize Author A. Name\\\normalsize email@example.com\\\normalsize Awesome Department\\\normalsize Big Deal University}
\date{}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5in}{-0.5in}\begin{center}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\end{center}}{\end{center}\end{adjustwidth}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\maketitle
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `showframe` option was used only to have a visual guideline.

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't seem to work with the \maketitle command. The text was forced onto a second page.

Comment: @drb please see the second example code in my updated answer.