# change title page margins ONLY without packages

Tags: margins, titles, package-writing

I am trying to prepare a package for students that offers a uniform standard title page for their work (homework, reports, theses, and probably more).

I have the title page laid out as it should be. However, I am having problems setting the margins. I wish to centre ONLY the title page, without side effects to possible margin settings that the students might have already set up for the rest of their document.

I have seen other solutions [such as this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page), but they invariably make use of some package like `geometry` etc. I am seeking a solution that works with plain LaTeX only. The reason is that I do not know what class the title page package ends up in (`book`, `report`, `memoir`, `classicthesis`, ...), and I need something that provides maximum compatibility.

Comment: Are they using pdfLaTeX? If so, just create a separate class to produce just the title page and have them use the `pdfpages` package to include it. Nothing you do is going to be compatible *inline* with absolutely anything they might be using.

Comment: I don't know what they are using. And I have thought about the `pdfpages` solution, as this is what I do for my own thesis title page. But for someone maybe new to TeX, and more importantly maybe already struggling to get the required work done, a two-step process is far worse than accepting small incompatibilities with e.g. the `geometry` package. And since `geometry` does it, it should be doable, right?

Comment: It is going to break somebody's document. Bound to.  What do you mean by `plain LaTeX` exactly? Note that classes and packages do not just add things, they change things. So, by `\begin{document}`, `\macroA` may not do the same thing in student 1's document as it does in student 2's. I'm no guru but everything I know suggests that you simply can't do this in a way which will be compatible with every student's work: not if they could be using literally any combination of class and packages. Not using a package doesn't mean compatible with everything. Packages are just code. Code changes stuff.

Comment: Of course people might load packages and break stuff. I merely wish to minimise the way in which *my code* does likewise. The question is simply how to achieve in a standalone way what the `\newgeometry`, `\restoregeometry`, ... commands from `geometry` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to borrow the definitions for the `\changepage` command from the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% Definitions taken from changepage.sty
\begingroup
\catcode`\Q=3
\long\gdef\@ifmtarg#1{\@xifmtarg#1QQ\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo\@nil}
\long\gdef\@xifmtarg#1#2Q#3#4#5\@nil{#4}
\endgroup

% Set the page output parameters
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ch@ngetext}{%
  \setlength{\@colht}{\textheight}\setlength{\@colroom}{\textheight}%
  \setlength{\vsize}{\textheight}\setlength{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \if@twocolumn%
    \advance\columnwidth-\columnsep \divide\columnwidth\tw@%
    \@firstcolumntrue%
  \fi%
  \setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\changepage}[9]{%
  \@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\addtolength{\textheight}{#1}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#2}{}{\addtolength{\textwidth}{#2}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#3}{}{\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{#3}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#4}{}{\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{#4}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#5}{}{\addtolength{\columnsep}{#5}}%
  \ch@ngetext%
  \@ifmtarg{#6}{}{\addtolength{\topmargin}{#6}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#7}{}{\addtolength{\headheight}{#7}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#8}{}{\addtolength{\headsep}{#8}}%
  \@ifmtarg{#9}{}{\addtolength{\footskip}{#9}}}
\makeatother
%
%\changepage{<textheight>}{<textwidth>}{<even-side-margin>}{<odd-side-margin>}{<columnsep>}{<topmargin>}{<headheight>}{<headsep>}{<footskip>}  

\begin{document}

\changepage{7cm}{6cm}{-3cm}{-3cm}{}{-3cm}{}{}{}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\changepage{-7cm}{-6cm}{3cm}{3cm}{}{3cm}{}{}{}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I have renamed the command to something unique for the package, in case someone uses `changepage`.

Comment: @nes I thought you wanted a standard title page? This gives a different result for `memoir` than it does for `report`, and a different result again for `book`.

Comment: @nes Try `\documentclass{book}`, `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{geometry}`, `\documentclass{memoir}`. (Restricting to classes which default to double-sided.) Or `\documentclass{report}`. (For one which doesn't.)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your concern, I take one/twoside and one/twocolumn into account when laying out the title. I really only needed a means to change the geometry for a single page.