# How to set geometry pack to standard after title page

Tags: margins, titles, geometry, default

I'm using `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` for my whole document but want to adjust the geometry of the title page. I have seen [this solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31705/different-margins-for-title-page). My problem is that I don't know what values I have to submit to `newgeometry` command after the title page. It should look exactly like `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` on all pages after title.

Comment: Have you tried to use `\restoregeometry` after the title page as shown in the second answer? If so, please show a minimal working example, that shows what you've tried. If not, please try it. If it does not help, also show a minimal working example, that shows exactly what you've tried without success.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks. That solves my problem!

Comment: In this case, IMHO this question should be closed as duplicate because it is already solved by an answer to the linked question.

Comment: @cabohah That's fine for me.